# Finding the difference between two temperature

Tags: c++

I have a function that is supposed to find the difference between two temp's.  First off all I print out Celsius and approx Fahrenheit and then I find and print the difference between them.  My problem is all that happens when I run the program is that the output for difference is 58 for everything.

Where as it should print out something like this:

```
C----AF----Diff
1----32----31
2----34----32
```

etc.

My code:

```
void calDiff(int& cel, int& appFar, int diff){
while(cel!= 101){
    diff = appFar - cel;
    cout << diff << endl;
    cel++;
    appFar++;
}
}
```

Comment: This is math fail :). If you increment both the difference stays the same.

Comment: For your code, `58` for everything is right.

Comment: @user2280716 Hmm, well I have no Idea how to do it then, maybe thats why I fail everything to do with maths :)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Thomas Ya I know I was just trying to be funny. It didn't work. Anyways where do the cel and appFar come from? user input?

Comment: @user2280716 It's another function that uses a loop to generate them, but I have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a function to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.
2. You don't want to change `cel` and `appFar`, then remove the reference `&`.

```
int cel2far(int cel)
{
     // convert cel to far and return approx. far
}

void calDiff(int cel, int appFar, int diff)
{
    while(cel!= 101){
        diff = appFar - cel;
        cout << diff << endl;
        cel++;
        appFar = cel2far(cel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You increment both the celcius and fahrenheit tempertures by one each loop, therefore the difference will be the same everytime.  Just because you pass the temperature by reference doesn't mean it will recalculate the fahrenheit for you when you change it.  You should increment celcius by one, recalculate the fahrenheit then calculate the difference.